# .access RedirectMatch doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /old_folder/ /$1
```

I want to redirect from

```
https://sslconnection.de/website.de/old_folder/
```

to

```
https://sslconnection.de/website.de/
```

Including all sites in old_folder/. But I always get this error in Firefox:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

Cookies are accepted. Where is my mistake?

EDIT:
Maybe it's caused by:

```
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
```

I have read that i need Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/website.de/old_folder/ /website.de/
```

in the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: I've tried this. Now I don't get an error but it doesn't do anything either :/